# A Problematic Lagrange moltiplicators problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Well, I Bring you the following problem:

Determine the image of $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)= \log(x+4) + \log(y+4)$

$A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^{2}}: (x-2)^{2} + (y-2)^{2} \le1,   y\le2\}  $

attempt of solution:
I put the conditions on general form:

$(x-2)^{2} + (y-2)^{2}-1 \le0$ $=$ $g(x,y)$

$y-2$ $\le$ $0$ $=$ $h(x,y)$

Then, the expression to work on will be: 
$T=f(x,y) - Lg(x,y) -Gh(x,y)$ were L and G are the Lagrange multipliers

at this point I do the partial derivatives:

$\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{x}}= \frac{1}{x+4}-2L(x-2)$ $=0$

$\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{y}}= \frac{1}{y+4}-2L(y-2)-G$ $=0$

$\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{L}}$= $-(x-2)^{2} - (y-2)^2$ $=0$

$\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{G}}$= $-(y-2)$ $=0$

For some reason I don't find any congruent solutions for this system.

Thanks for your help

PS: hint, maybe is necessary to use the reduction theorem to study the $\partial{A}$.

Comment: Fine. Now bring us a reason to find that more interesting than other problems.

Comment: Do you have to find the extrema or the image of a set under a function?

Comment: The image of the set under the given function.